# Debugging Responsive File Manager Plugin (TinyMCE)

Tags: tinymce, image-uploading, file-manager

Yesterday I found this great looking plugin for file and image management for tinymce however I cannot get the files to actually save to the drive. I have tried every commbination I can think of.

responsivefilemanager.com - This plugin.

Anyone used it before and know of the settings I might need?

The plugin sits here: **/public_html/cms/app/webroot/js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager**

I'm trying to set it up so the uploads go here: **/public_html/cms/app/webroot/files/cms**

The config file for the plugin has 3 lines to configure for this, these are as follows and as I have set them up:

```
$base_url="http://domain.com/cms/";  // base url of site. If you prefer relative urls leave empty
$upload_dir = 'app/webroot/files/cms/'; // path from base_url to base of upload folder
$current_path = '../../../files/cms/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder
```

Now when I started working this out I would get an error for the plugin saying the root folder doesn't exist so I keep playing with the paths and now I don't get this error but I still cannnot get it to upload the images, everything looks like it works, I get the preview as the image is uploading and a green tick once it's complete then I go back to the files list and the image isn't there. It's not on the server either. I'm wondering if there is a way to debug this and work out what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I use this plugin but I get this error "The path is not writable" the folder is already 777, have you any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work with the following settings:

```
$base_url="http://domain.com";  // base url of site. 

$upload_dir = '/cms/app/webroot/files/cms/'; // path from base_url to base of upload folder

$current_path = '../../../../files/cms/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following settings if you still have not got this sorted out yet:

$base_url="http://www.domain.com/cms";  // base url of site. If you prefer relative urls leave empty --> No trailing slash

// The upload directory will be a dir you have created for the files to be uploaded to, ie: localhost/cms/app/webroot/files/cms --> this file must have write permission.

$upload_dir = '/app/webroot/files/cms/'; // path from base_url to base of upload folder --> write permission (chmod = 755)

$current_path = '../../../../files/cms/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (you are missing one "../")

// The thumbs folder located in tinymce/plugins/filemanager/thumbs must also have write permission (chmod = 755)

That should do it

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later when I am near the code again and let you know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks I just tried these settings and I get this error in the popup: There is an error! The root folder not exist.

Answer (score -3):

use gsynuhimgupload plugin TinyMCE

http://gsynuh.com/tinymce-simple-image-uploader/136

TinyMCE simple image uploader

Here’s a repost of my TinyMCE image uploader plugin. It used to be on gsynuh-labs.com (but I let this domain go).
please note that this plugin is no longer supported by me – and I’m not responsible for any inconvenience caused by it, it is shared “as-is” and you have to be responsible when using it ie: take care of any possible injection problems/security problems in your own site’s context.
I’m not interested in expanding it myself as I was only looking for a very minimal image uploading plugin for myself but If you are going to expand on it, I can list your version on this page if you want, just contact me.

—