# How can I change the default responsive filemanager upload path?

Tags: php, responsive-filemanager

I am using responsive filemanager in my system. And I separated the upload folder in its default path. So I made a folder named `file_uploads` in my root.

What I did so far is:

I edited config.php `base_url` path

```
$current_base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ! in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']), array( 'off', 'no' ))) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$current_project_path = '/mysystem/file_uploads';

$config = array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DON'T TOUCH (base url (only domain) of site).
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | without final / (DON'T TOUCH)
    |
    */
    'base_url' => $current_base_url . $current_project_path,
```

And when I try to upload a file there's no error. And when I check the details inside my filemanager the path is correct but when I checked my file if it is in my new directory (source/thumbs) there's no file there. And when I checked the default path (source/thumbs) my uploaded file is there.

Comment: Please follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282372/debugging-responsive-file-manager-plugin-tinymce